# Installation script with reboot

Tags: shell-script, software-installation

Can any guide to shell or python script that has multiple installations, but in between it restart Linux system and continue from there...

1. `apt-get install package1`
2. `apt-get install package2`
3. `reboot`
4. `apt-get install package3`
5. `apt-get install package4`

I will initiate the installation but during it has to take several reboots, and finish all installations. After finishing job, I will delete the file.

Comment: Couldn't the first script create an @reboot cronjob which executes the second script, and the second scripts deletes the cronjob after it runs?

Would someone clarify why the question is downvoted? I am just curious.

Comment: I would create a script, using a state variable in some file to control the successive installation steps, and add this script as  init script or systemd unit depending on your boot scheme.